# sliderbar is not coming on top of other layouts

Tags: android

I have a releative layout which contain 2 arrows after that i kept sliding drawer.when i press on slidingdrawer its coming only upto relativelayout.it has to occupy entire screen.can anyone help me on this

Comment: Can't help without you pasting your xml :)

Answer (score 0):

> when i press on slidingdrawer its coming only upto relativelayout.it has to occupy entire screen

Your `SlidingDrawer` needs to be a child of a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` that fills up the screen. [Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/DrawerDemo/) demonstrating this, using a `FrameLayout`.